# Getting a multi-dimensional array of bytes from a Texture2D in unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am currently testing a neural net in Unity, which takes in a very specific configuration of inputs. The input the net takes is (ImageHeight, ImageWidth, 3) in bytes. I am currently trying to do this by reading in the data from GetRawByteData() but the network is not working.

(Before anyone says anything, the network isn't the problem, as I used a different library to handle this on Windows. On Mac (which I am currently working on), this specific library (OpenCVSharp) doesn't work.)

Here was what I tried in Unity:

```
        Texture2D Image = currenttexture;
        byte[] colors = Image.GetRawTextureData();
        byte[,,,] floatarray = new byte[ Image.height, Image.width, 3];


        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Image.height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Image.width; j++)
            {
                floatarray[ i, j, 0] = colors[k];
                floatarray[ i, j, 1] = colors[k+1];
                floatarray[ i, j, 2] = colors[k+2];
                k+=4;
            }
        }
```

Is there any 'accepted' way to do this, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does your code throw an error, or a particular problem symptom? And what format is your texture?

Comment: My texture has a format of RGBA32, but the net wants it RGB (one byte for each channel per pixel). When fed into the net, the net doesn't work and outputs around the same values no matter what the image.